# How to rewrite SQL like query into elasticsearch?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

How would you rewrite this query into elasticsearch query?

`SELECT * FROM` products `WHERE (`name`like 'captain%' or`name`like '%captain%' OR`manufacturer `like '%captain%')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basics:**

- OR   -> should
- AND  -> must

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (name like 'captain%' or name like '%captain%' OR manufacturer like '%captain%')
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (name like '%captain%' OR manufacturer like '%captain%')
```

The equivalent ES query would be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "*captain*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "manufacturer": {
              "value": "*captain*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```